# Bold text inside .html( )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to format text inside `.html( )`.
In the code below I want to make bold of text **Ctrl + D** in *'Press Ctrl + D to bookmark this page.'*

I tried with `<b>Ctrl + D</b>`, but this does not work.

```html
<p id="rfact"></p>
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#rfact').html(function() {
        if (/Mac/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            return 'Press U+2318 + D to bookmark this page.';
        } else {
            return 'Press Ctrl + D to bookmark this page.';
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: ```'Press <strong> Ctrl + D </strong> to bookmark this page.';```? Does that solve your problem ? Also see if the strong is being rendered as markup tag or not.

Comment: Works fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/mrsqd6n4/  Maybe you have some random css that changes `<b>` (or `<strong>`) style so it's not bold (which is why they started using "strong" as you could make "b" not bold, so it made no sense)

Comment: Can you generate a proper snippet ([edit] and click `[<>]`) showing exactly what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I place your piece of code in a fiddle, take a look.
https://jsfiddle.net/8cduL3k6/1/

Definitely putting the text between `strong` should work. Consider looking the developer console to check for any inconsistency or error message to guide us.

Another trick you can try, is wrap your shortcut in `span` tags, and use `.css()` method to stylize your text to bold.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#rfact').html(function() {
    if (/Mac/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            return 'Press <span>U+2318 + D</span> to bookmark this page.';
        }
    else {
            return 'Press <span>Ctrl + D</span> to bookmark this page.';
    }
   }).find('span').css('fontWeight', 'bold');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try `<strong>Ctrl + D</strong>`? or maybe try to switch to `.text()` istead of `.html()`

Comment: No it does not work. It shows <strong>Ctrl + D</strong> instead of making it bold

Comment: ok, im searching for a solution

Comment: that's weird. <b> should work too: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_set)

Comment: If it shows the text `"<strong>Ctrl + D</strong>"` then you're using `.text(....` instead of `.html(...` - your question states `.html(...` so will not escape the html tags.

Comment: re edit: it should definitely *not* be `.text()` if OP wants html tags...  it *probably is* `.text()` already and OP hasn't provided their actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
  if (/Mac/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
     $('#rfact').html('Press U+2318 + D to bookmark this page.');
     } else {
     $('#rfact').html('Press <strong>Ctrl + D</strong> to bookmark this page.';
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try with vanilla js

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (/Mac/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.getElementById('rfact').innerHTML = 'Press U+2318 + D to bookmark this page.';   
    } else {
        document.getElementById('rfact').innerHTML =  'Press <strong> Ctrl + D </strong> to bookmark this page.';
    }
}) ;
```

Or with jquery just replace the section `document.getElementById` with `$('#rfact').html(text)`